# error showing while try to inserting table data containing img through php codes are as following:

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php
$t1 = $_POST['t1'];
$t2 = $_POST['t2'];
$t3 = $_POST['t3'];
$t4 = $_POST['t4'];
$t5 = $_POST['t5'];
$t6 = $_POST['t6'];
$t7 = $_POST['t7'];
$t8 = $_POST['t8'];
$t9 = $_POST['t9'];



$connect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','agni','gyaninfra');
mysqli_query($connect,"insert into employee 
values($t1,'$t2','$t3','$t4','$t5',$t6,'$t7','$t8','t9');");
if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0){
header("location:emp.php");

}  else {
    echo "data NOT Added<br />";
echo "<a href='emp.php'>Go Back</a>";
echo mysqli_error ($connect);
}
?>
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com,'8409503845','navadih','20.3kb.jpg')' at line 1

Comment: `insert into employee 
values('$t1','$t2','$t3','$t4','$t5','$t6','$t7','$t8','t9');`

Answer (score 0):

Your $t1 and $t6 in query is without quotes. Shoud be like this

```
mysqli_query($connect,"insert into employee 
values('$t1','$t2','$t3','$t4','$t5','$t6','$t7','$t8','t9');");
```

Comment: `$t6` also not in quotes.